# Magento 2 Error Uncaugt Type Error: cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'remove') customer-data.js

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

[image]

I tried to fix this issue but had no luck.
I also updated the customer-data.js with this.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31940/files#diff-505571b5dff3524c909c283778bf3d9b63338ae15de2eb3dce8850107fba49dc

Comment: Hi Wang, can you please share what is the purpose of your requirement and what are you trying to achieve by customizing this customer-data.js file? This will help us find more ways to solution. Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't want to customize the customer-data.js.
But it's showing the "Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'remove')".